# How can I get a SAML security token for a user logged in via SSO in WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, sts-securitytokenservice, wso2-identity-server

I have WSO2 Identity Server set up together with a web application that is configured for SAML 2.0 SSO.

When a user has authenticated, I want to invoke a SOAP service from this application. The SOAP service trusts the Identity Server and is protected with WS-Security. It expects a SAML 2.0 token in the request.

Is it possible for the application to get a SAML token from the WSO2 STS for the currently logged-in user?

The STS seems to require username/password (or X.509 certificate) to authenticate the user, which I don't have in the application (I have only the username).

Is there another way apart from the STS to get a token for the logged-in user?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm with the same problem, if you have any tips you could share here. tks!!

Comment: did you get a solution for this. I am in a similar fix.

Comment: No, we did not investigate this any further. It was just an evaluation and we used a different solution for our use case.